# Show loading gif whilst image is loading

Tags: jquery, loader

I have the following list, and when the user clicks an li, I want the ul.list to hide and then show the div.single and at the same time set the img.data-img src to the data-img of the li, but whilst it is loading I want to set the img src to the loader.gif which is inside the li element.

```
<ul class="list">
<li data-id="7" data-thumb="http://test.com/assets/pdc/thumbs/66.png" data-img="http://test.com/assets/pdc/img/66.png" data-country="Australia" data-company="Big Farm" data-app="Tea" data-brand="Big Farm" data-package="500" class="product air-500 cat7">
    <img class="tip" data-country="Australia" data-brand="Big Farm" src="assets/img/ajax-loader.gif">
</li>
</ul>

<div class="single">
<img class="data-img" src="">
</div>

var preloader = $(this).find('.tip').attr('src');

$('.single aside img').attr('src', preloader);
$('.single aside img').attr('src', url).load(function () { 
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be really difficult to tell when an image has loaded; you may just want to preload the image (using `$("<img>").attr('src', src)` is enough).

You could rely on `.load`, but in my experience it's not 100%:

```
$("li").on('click', function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   //Show the throbber
   $this.find('.tip').show();

   //After image finishes loading, hide the `ul.list`
   $(".single .data-img").attr('src', $this.data-img).load(function () {
      $this.closest('.list').hide();    
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that, it works but I want the .list to hide straight away really, instead of waiting until the image loads, because this leaves a kind of delay when the user clicks on the li, which might confuse them. I'd rather it show the div.single then and show the loader while the data-img is loading.

Comment: Is there anything in the `div.single`?  Where do you want to show the throbber (gif)?  It's inside the `<li>`, which you would hide right away.

Comment: sorry yes the last div should have been closed, check code again, the img is inside div.single. I want to show the loading gif in div.single i.e. set the src of div.single img to the loader gif.

Comment: @user1937021 you can't do that and load the image simultaneously, but you could append the throbber image to `.single` instead (so you have both images).

Comment: check the javascript I used in the edited original post, it works to some extent but it gets the data-thumb instead of the loader gif.